# Which exchanges offer stop-loss functionality?

Tags: exchanges, trading, market

In case of a sudden price drop, I want to sell my coins automatically. MtGox doesn't have an option for this, which exchanges do?

Comment: But then you contribute to the price falling. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @ZekeSonxx: With stop-loss you can save at least part of your portfolio's value, the externality of course is you contribute to the price fall. Without it, you absorb all the value loss instead of passing it onto others - hopefully, if enough people stand in line stoichly absorbing their losses, price won't descend further.. O, Tragedy of the Commons!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kraken.com](https://www.kraken.com/) offers a number of advanced trading options and a good guide on how to use them.

Advanced Order Types:

- Stop Loss
- Stop Loss
- Limit Trailing
- Stop Trailing
- Stop Limit
- Take Profit
- Take Profit Limit
- Stop, Limit
- Stop Loss, Take Profit
- Stop Loss, Take Profit Limit

Though their volume is very low for USD trades,(limiting liquidity), they are popular for EURO-BTX trades and offer fee-less SEPA transfers and low trade fees.

Comment: This is [no longer true](https://blog.kraken.com/post/1234/announcement-delisting-pairs-and-temporary-suspension-of-advanced-order-types/)  for Kraken, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

[BTX Trader](http://btxtrader.com) will let you [create stop-loss orders](http://blog.btxtrader.com/post/67381472043/prevent-bitcoin-trading-losses-with-stop-limit-orders) on top of your account on Bitstamp, BTC-E, Mt. Gox, BTC China and CampBX.

It's not same as an exchange-hosted stop-loss order but a close second.

Disclosure: I'm one of the founders of BTX Trader.

Comment: The problem with BTX Trader is that its a desktop client, so when I shutdown my computer, the stop-loss will not be triggered. An alternative would be www.bitcoin-bot.com, which is a hosted solution, but the problem with external stop-loss scripts is that your order will not be executed in the same 'order' as it would be with native stop-loss.

Comment: The stop loss orders on BTX Trader are hosted on the backend. They will execute even if the desktop client is not running.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at

https://www.bitfinex.com/

Also has trailing stop, limit orders, CFD and margin trades.

Answer (score 2):

I think https://campbx.com/ allows this, I don't know of any others.

Comment: Nope.  Their site has since 2011 listed that as a feature but still no stops.

Answer (score 0):

yes, stop-loss or stop limit are offered by BitKonan https://bitkonan.com/

but market must be liquid enough to make this function working

Answer (score 0):

Binance now has stop loss orders.

https://support.binance.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003372072

Answer (score -1):

www.bitrule.com assists Bitcoin users to mitigate price volatility by placing custom trading rules such as stop loss as well as creating price alerts.
Designed to be simple, Bitrule is a cloud based service that connects to all major Bitcoin exchanges and safeguards your bitcoins even while you're asleep.

No software downloads, no browser plug-ins required and no deposits. Simply login your  account, place rules & alerts
goodluck...
http://www.bitrule.com